# change css value depending on browser width

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i really need some help with this:

[Click me for example](http://i.imagebanana.com/img/2ml2dm3p/Unbenannt1.jpg)

i have a div container #green (green border) with a bg image. the div is on 100% width and the bg image with css3's -cover-. In this div is another div #red which has a position absolute and right value. i want force the #red div to have always the same distance between a motive of the bg image. means if im scaling the browser window the gap should always be the same.
my try was to divide the `#red { right: 25px }` css by `$(window).width()` and use this factor for

```
var factor = 0,253;
var width = $(window).width()*factor;

('#red').css('right', width);
```

but it does not work. hope you get my point, and every help would be much appreciated :)

Comment: I guess being an architect didn't work out for you, huh?

Answer (score 2):

Use [media queries](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/):

```
@media (min-width:500px) { … }
```

Comment: See [this tutorial](http://www.netmagazine.com/tutorials/build-responsive-site-week-media-queries-part-4) to see how to use it

Comment: thanks, but really, whats wrong with my method to do it? i mean i dont want it responsive on resize. just when the site loads... what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Media queries work both ways (which is how you *should* want it to be). If you want it to only work on load then you'll be limited to a JavaScript only solution.

Comment: yeah but thats the point! its okay to use js only, but look at my example, do i have a logical fault?

Comment: okay it works with `left`i dont know why, but it does! thank you anyway for your effort :)

Answer (score 0):

`var factor = 0,253` is invalid syntax

SHould be

```
var factor = 0.253;
```

Use a browser console to check errors, this would pop right out